# Using Google Drive Api on android studio?

Tags: api, android-studio, drive

i am working on app that integrates google drive api to upload/download files from the user's Google Drive account. i am using
this documentation [google drive api v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads), but it dont work,
i got this error ->
'java.net.MalformedURLException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference', i can login into google account and log out, but cant uplodad files

```
public Task<String> newFile(String filepath) {
    return Tasks.call(executor, () -> {
        File fmdt = new File();
        fmdt.setName("contents.json");
        java.io.File fp = new java.io.File(filepath);
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/json",fp);
        File mf = null;
        try {
           
            mf = driveService.files().create(fmdt, mediaContent).setFields("id").execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("usr","drive-> "+e.getMessage() );
        }
        if (mf == null) {
            throw new IOException("null result");
        }
        return mf.getId();
    });

}
```

Comment: FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/json",fp)   ;  mf = driveService.files().create(fmdt, mediaContent).setFields("id").execute(); error is caused by these lines, if i remove mediaContent from create like this ' mf = driveService.files().create(fmdt).setFields("id").execute();'  it works but upload a empty file,             but still cant solve

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes i solve it, if you need solution repli this

Comment: Yes I do need one! Maybe you can post it as a reply of your question

Comment: sorry for the time i was a little busy

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solve, i guest you re actualli singin on goggle

//the class that handle upload request

```
public class GoogleDriveHelper {
private final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private final Drive driveService;

public GoogleDriveHelper(Drive mDriveService) {
    this.driveService = mDriveService;
}
public Task<String> newFile(String fileName, String path, String parentId, File file) {
    return Tasks.call(executor, () -> {
        
        //use parent to save in especific folder
        File fmdt = new File()
                .setParents(Collections.singletonList(parentId))
                .setMimeType("application/octet-stream")
                .setName(nfileName);
        File mf = null;
       
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/octet-stream", file);
        try {
            mf = driveService.files().create(fmdt, mediaContent).setFields("id").execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (mf == null) {
            throw new IOException("null result");
        }
        return mf.getId();
    });
}}
```

//inicialize google drive service

```
 val credential =
                GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    ctx,
                    Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE)
                )
            credential.selectedAccount = account!!.account
            gService = Drive.Builder(
                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                GsonFactory(),
                credential
            ).
            setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
            gDrivehelper = GoogleDriveHelper(gService)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer! Unfortunately I'm not sure what is the deal maker here. I see you've changed the MimeType, which I've tried but it didn't work. I also see you've added a parentId, but shouldn't it work without one?

Comment: Do you have an idea of what prevents the MalformedURLException in the code above?

Comment: Check wich version of cliente are you using, i use 1.26.0